# Needing help debugging

Tags: html

I'm creating my program on w3school which it does not provide any debugging tools at all, I basically finished my project on there but later found out I had 80+ errors that needs fixing which I'm given super generic answers so I can't seem to figure out what exactly the issue is. I'm a super newbie at HTML and unlike java where eclipse at least tells you where exactly the error is at and gives you a little better info I have no idea what the errors mean. I am also using w3school file upload method to debug my program. Also my program is basically just a tv schedule having the days, time, and each shows broken down

I've tried googling some answers but its not really helping

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
<title>Tv Schedule</title>
</head>
<body>

 <table>
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"/>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white">
        <th style="background-color:black;color:white">Monday</th>
        <th style="background-color:black;color:white">Tuesday</th> 
        <th style="background-color:black;color:white">Wednesday</th>
        <th style="background-color:black;color:white">Thursday</th> 
        <th style="background-color:black;color:white">Friday</th>
        <th style="background-color:black;color:white">Saturday</th> 
        <th style="background-color:black;color:white">Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>12:00pm</th>
        <th rowspan="4" style="background-color:purple">Ben & Jerry's show</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="background-color:yellow">The Happy Mile</th>
        <th rowspan="3" colspan="3" style="background-color:teal">That Yesterday Show</th>
        <th rowspan="4" style="background-color:lime">Let them Running Cat</th>
        <th rowspan="4" style="background-color:red">Run Talk</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;color:white">12:30pm</th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>1:00pm</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="background-color:green">The Laptop Conspiracy</th>
      <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;color:white">1:30pm</th>
        <th rowspan="3" colspan="2" style="background-color:tan">Cat Street</th>
        <th style="background-color:royalblue">Slept News</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <th>2:00pm</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="background-color:Turquoise">Slept</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="3" style="background-color:RosyBrown">Adultsnado 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;color:white">2:30pm</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>3:00pm</th>
        <th colspan="5" style="background-color:SandyBrown">Citizen Yang</th>
        <th rowspan="3" style="background-color:aqua">Slept</th>
        <th rowspan="5" style="background-color:burlywood">Computer Wars</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;color:white">3:30pm</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="background-color:lightsteelblue">Lionnado 4</th>
        <th rowspan="3" colspan="2" style="background-color:Olive">Citizen Moong</th>
       <th rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="background-color:Moccasin ">Dr. LongestRun</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>4:00pm</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;color:white">4:30pm</th> 
        <th rowspan="2" style="background-color:linen">The N/A part II</th>
        <th style="background-color:cornsilk">Back to the Season</th>
        <th colspan="2" style="background-color:MediumSpringGreen">Running Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>5:00pm</th>
        <th rowspan="3" style="background-color:MediumOrchid ">WWII Battle Obsession</th>
        <th colspan="4" style="background-color:lightyellow">The Fat Running Theory</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;color:white">5:30pm</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="background-color:indianred">Rebel without a computer</th>
        <th colspan="2" style="background-color:limegreen">Fighting Tomorrow</th>
        <th colspan="3" style="background-color:gold">Episode XVI - The Laptop Run</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>6:00pm</th>
        <th style="background-color:mistyrose">Spam TV</th>
        <th colspan="3" style="background-color:indianred">The Lion</th>
        <th style="background-color:mintcream">Running Yer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;color:white">6:30pm</th>
        <th rowspan="3" colspan="5" style="background-color:honeydew">Give God Money</th>
        <th rowspan="5" colspan="2" style="background-color:Fuchsia">Skinny Karaoke</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>7:00pm</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;color:white">7:30pm</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>8:00pm</th>
        <th rowspan="4" style="background-color:lavender">Eye of Thailand</th>
        <th style="background-color:orange">Slept News</th>
        <th style="background-color:orchid">Happy gossip</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;color:white">8:30pm</th>
        <th rowspan="3" colspan="2" style="background-color:DarkKhaki">Skinny Today</th>
        <th style="background-color:orange">Slept News</th>
        <th style="background-color:orchid">Happy gossip</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>9:00pm</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="3" style="background-color:Aquamarine">Soon Slept</th>
        <th rowspan="5" style="background-color:brown">America's Got Laptop</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;color:white">9:30pm</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>10:00pm</th>
        <th rowspan="3" colspan="5" style="background-color:chocolate">Don't run there</th>
        <th  rowspan="3" style="background-color:violet">North Fillory Fighting
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;color:white">10:30pm</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>11:00pm</th>
    </tr>
        <th style="background-color:white;color:white">11:30pm</th> 
        <th colspan="2" style="background-color:crimson">Captain Zeloous and Adult lads</th>
        <th style="background-color:yellowgreen">Grand Theft Computer</th>
        <th style="background-color:gray">Zealous Rerun</th>
        <th colspan="3" style="background-color:dodgerblue">Pay-Per-Download</th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I only get these types of errors,
-document type does not allow element "table" here

### -document type does not allow element "th" here

Comment: You're missing closing tags on most of your `<th>`, and you're using the `<font>` tag, which is obsolete, use the CSS styles like your background-color instead.

Comment: You may want to refrain from using `font` elements. They are not supported in HTML5

Comment: If I shouldnt use the font tag, is there another way I can change the color of the fonts ?

Comment: You can change font colors with the `color` style. Can be done with a style attribute (`style="color:red"`), or in the stylesheet, if you have one. In your case, one of your `th`s may look like `<th style="background-color:white;color:white">1:30pm</th>`

Comment: Awesome that helps a lot! If the work style or colspan is red does that mean its an error?

Comment: Red text does not mean an error. It is common for html attributes to be red.

Comment: Are my TR tags needed for the program to run the way I want it to look like? also is this line:  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"/> the best way to make it so there is no white gap between my color boxes since I'm not allowed to have those white gaps.

Comment: Table rows are very important for tables. You do have an extra opening `<tr>` tag right after the "Laptop Conspiracy" line

Comment: Its so weird those, as soon as I remove that it complete throws my schedule off

Comment: This page has turned into more of a personal debugging session. I am glad to be able to help, but in the overall structure of Stack Overflow, it may be best to revert your edits back to the original problem. This way the question is focused on a central issue that is answered so other users may find solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `head` and `body` tags. You need those for valid html. Your table must be contained in the `body` tag.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <!--All your table stuff-->
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also make sure you have all your closing tags. I noticed some missing `</th>` tags.

UPDATE: The xmlns attribute is required in XHTML, which you are using. You need to add said attribute to your `html` tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <!--head,body,etc-->
</html>
```

This can be found on [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_html_xmlns.asp)

The source of most of the problems you're facing is missing tags. When writing in any markup or programming language, make sure you have the same number of opening tags/braces/groupings as you do closing groupings at the same time as you go along. This problem can otherwise be harder to spot in code and can have some of the worst results.

Comment: So if I add the head do I still need to use thead? Also I tried adding some closing tags but when I do that it completely changes how my output is supposed to look like, do you know why that would be the case?

Comment: The `head` tag is for the html document as a whole. `thead` tags are for tables (table-head). I would need to see where you put these closing tags to tell what your document now looks like.

Comment: If it helps at all I was creating my program through w3school website to see how my output looks like. When using the validator for something like this, <html> its giving me a response of Missing xmlns attribute for element html. The value should be: http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml which I have no idea what its talking about. I also keep getting errors that this symbol > is being used wrong.

Comment: Sorry another question, for my days of the week, would that still go in the table tag or would it be right to leave it where I currently have it?

Comment: Your days of the week would remain in the table, but should not use `font`. Remember `th`s are just headers in tables, and should have text in them. Also, (just noticed this), some of your tags near the top of your document have extra `/` characters in the form `<table/></table>` and `<th/></th>`. That could cause a lot of problems. You are also missing the `thead` closing tag

Comment: Okay I just updated my program again, for some reason the the table and html tag close won't show up at the bottom. I changed the fonts for the week and my errors went down from 70 to 50 so that definitely helped a lot. But I'm still confuse where the rest of the 50 errors are.

Comment: Sorry I'm not really understanding the question

Comment: In the copy/paste you did with my answer, you copied over the `<table>` opening tag, which you already have. However, the one you do have should be in the form `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`, and not `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"/>`